# Why does JavaScript have different declarations for the same behavior?

Tags: javascript, html

Why should I declare

```
var foo = {}
```

instead of

```
var foo = new Object();
```

in JavaScript if they are similar?
Does the same applies to

```
foo[0].bar = new Function(){ "return hello"};
```

as in in

```
foo[0].bar = function(){return "hello"};
```

?
Is it an efficiency matter? Does it make difference?

Comment: I prefer the shorthand for the object constructor which I consider simpler and more readable (read as an empty object), but I've never seen your function constructor (?) in the first variation in practice.

Comment: Because it's not actually instated like that.  It's a function call, to a function-construction constructor-function, where you send in the names of parameters as strings, and the whole body of the function, as a string, is the last parameter, and it returns a function that it evals together.

Answer (score 2):

I remember reading the following from [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com/):

> `personObj=new Object();`
>
> This is a bad and unnecessary use of the `new` keyword. They should be
>   using and advocating the object literal syntax (`{}`) for creating new
>   objects.

It doesn't say why, only that we should.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure either, but seems like returning a `new` instance of an object is unnecessary when you can use the object literal syntax to create a new object.

Answer (score 2):

Actually

```
var foo = {}
```

and

```
var foo = new Object();
```

does the same thing (both expressions create an empty `Object`) but it's better to use shorter version (`object literal`), it takes less space time to write and another thing that using `object literal` you can create and assign values/properties to an `Object` as follows

```
person = {
    property1 : "Hello"
};
```

but using `new Object()` you need to create it first and then assign values/properties as follows

```
person = new Object();
person.property1 = "Hello";
```

In your second example (`function vs new function`) there is a difference because `new Function` is `slower` and you can take a look at [**this test here**](http://jsperf.com/function-vs-function/2).

Comment: Am I having an wrong assumption or the `new Function` constructor has to `eval`uate the passed string? In that sense, it goes as far as 100 times slower running in FF17a and 60 times slower in Chrome 20.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't any efficiency increase or decrease, its just shorthand like using ? : for if/else..

I always use shorthand {} but if you are going to have a beginner reading your code you may want to use new Object().

Comment: also var foo = []; is same as var foo = new Array();

Comment: ^ Not exactly, the `new Array()` constructor takes ambiguous parameters. `new Array(5)` returns an array with 5 undefined index values, while `new Array("5")` returns an array with one item containing the string `5`. I'd go with the shorthand which is less ambiguous and easier to type.

Answer (score 0):

The only times it might matter is if your writing a program that generates such javascript dynamically ... or your writing for a certain teacher in college who seems to have a certain standard that doesn't quite make sense at times.

Answer (score 0):

The `new Function()` constructor doesn't really work that way.

It's called like:

```
var myFunc = new Function("param1", "param2", "message", "/*function-body-as-a-string*/ console.log(message); return param1 + \"=\" + param2;");
```

ie: really dumb, error-prone, stupid-slow (uses eval) and a security-hole.
Don't use it.

Comment: but why does it returns `"return word"` instead of `return "hello"`?

Comment: Do you have an example case?

Did you remember to add `"word"` (including quotes) as the first parameter to the constructor?  Did you accidentally quote the parameter inside of the function-body string?

 `var sayWord = new Function("word", "return word;");` should work, whereas `var sayWord2 = new Function("return 'word';");` will return "word" every time.

There are all sorts of reasons that this constructor is a *horrible* idea.

The other function-makers: function-expressions and function statements have benefits.  Function-construction just makes your code a security-risk and slow.